# How do I check the status of a bug report?

Tags: support, bug-reports

There was a small but significant usability problem reported with the design of Personal Finance & Money.  This was reported on [meta.money.SE 12 months ago](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1932/10997).  Despite having a high question score and having the bug reported [more than once](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1966/10997), it has never been addressed or even acknowledged by StackExchange personnel.

Is this issue being tracked somewhere?  Is there a way to determine whether or not the report has been seen by StackExchange designers and is planned to be fixed?  Is there something else that needs to be done to report the bug besides posting to the meta.money.SE site?

Comment: It takes 4-6 _<insert timeframe here>_ for many bugs to be fixed. But on a serious note, they do internally track the bugs.  I'd guess that the increase in designers at SE might move along some of the design bugs that are out there waiting to be addressed.

Comment: @bluefeet blasphemy!! It's 6-8!!!!!111

Comment: Yeah, yeah, yeah - I can't edit it now - I may have been feeling generous and I've already had this discussion with someone else @ShadowWizard :)

Comment: @Sha and I already said it but my comment got nuked by diamond :D

Comment: @nicael you can see it this way: you get more attention than usual, it can be a good thing... :D

Comment: This appears to be fixed with [the updates to money.SE](http://meta.money.stackexchange.com/q/2140/10997) last week.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is being tracked.

Jin & Company are working on unifying designs across the network to make fixing stuff like this easier, which should eventually mean faster fixes (and fewer bugs to begin with) - unfortunately, this has delayed a lot of individual fixes.

I'll pass this particular one along to see if we can expedite it.

Comment: Is Jin & Company a subsidiary of SE? :)

Comment: Subsidiary / shadow organization / something like that.

Comment: Triad backed, IIRC