# Bugs reported for android app

Tags: support, android-app, bug-reports

On Google+ page for "Stack Exchange Android App Alpha Testing" and elsewhere  we're directed right here for Bug Reporting.

What should happen **next**? How do we even know that our report was noticed by the dev team?

For example, there is a bug (or bugs) that prevent Android users to see bodies of certain questions and/ or answers.  It has been reported multiple times (including once by yours truly).  While some of the posts were marked as *duplicates*, **none** of them got any replies.

So what is the procedure? Is it reasonable to expect our bug reports acknowledged?  How can we learn whether they are being worked on and when the fix can be expected?

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186803/why-dont-we-get-responses-from-bug-reports and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250552/how-do-i-check-the-status-of-a-bug-report

Comment: @Shadow Wizard : With all due respect "related" is not neccessarily a "duplicate".  My question is not asking **how** or **where** to report.  I'm asking about what happens (should happen) *after* a report is posted and none of the other posts aaddress this question.

Comment: "what is the procedure?" sounds to me the same as "How does one report a bug?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This guy:

[image: Kasra]

That guy reads ALL of your bug reports. Sometimes he responds, sometimes he just weeps silently, sometimes he frames them and places on his bedside table so that he can meditate on them during those hours between night and dawn when we are meant to think about the past and what it means for our future.

When he responds, you should be glad. But when he *doesn't* respond, you should anticipate the future - for this means he is thinking, hard, about what your report means for *his* future and that of his team.

This being Android, it inevitably means *pain*...

Comment: He looks kind of sad. What did you do to him?!

Comment: On a more serious note can you please escalate [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231354/android-app-intermittently-shows-blank-answer-body-multiple-sites)? Almost a full year, and looks like more and more people are being affected.

Comment: @ShadowWizard been working on reproducing that bug all week. It's come up in the app from many different bugs in the past, trying to figure out what's causing it this time is being rougher than expected.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi thanks, can't you ask users having this issue send you internal logs that might help debug? (noticed iOS app got such option)

Comment: @ShadowWizard just had a talk with shog about this actually. The issue is the last few times the similar bug has happened it's all been causes that are very difficult to measure (e.g. "Oh the view is just full on transparent, but all the text is still there") --- the next beta build, if it doesn't fix this, will have some sort of watchdog to log when we can guess that the post isn't visible.

Comment: Can we (testers) help in any way?